# CUDA: argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "void *"

Tags: cuda, nsight

when I defined two float arrays like this:

```
float* d_A, d_B;
cudaMemcpy(d_B,h_B,size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

I receive an error concerning array **d_B**

> argument of type "float" is incompatible with parameter of type "void
>   *"

if I defined the arrays like this:

```
float* d_A;
float* d_B;
```

it works fine and the error disappears.
what can be wrong here ?
I'm using NSight Visual Studio edition version 3.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `*` specifing the pointer belongs to the variable, not the type. So to initialize it on the same line, use

```
float *d_A, *d_B;
```

Putting the `*` next to the variable with no space makes it much more obvious as well.